# IE triggered from c# Web service not opening UI

Tags: c#, web-services, powershell, internet-explorer

This is what I am trying to achieve :

1. I have a client window application with "Trigger Process" button
2. On "Trigger Process" click, it should call a web service called "DataRefresh"
3. "DataRefresh" service should trigger a PowerShell script through a batch file. which would open IE browser and will click a button.

For some security reasons, we are not letting the windows app to open the browser. So far I have made it work till triggering PowerShell script. **Here is the Problem** I have :

- IE triggered through web service is not opening the User Interface, but I see IE process in task manager.

**PS Script :**

```
param ([string]$managerefrehURL)
$ie = New-Object -ComObject 'internetExplorer.Application'  
$ie.Navigate($managerefrehURL)
$ie.Visible= $true
while ($ie.Busy -eq $true){Start-Sleep -seconds 1;}   

#click Also refresh as soon as possible button, check box ID ends with _cbRunNow

$checkBox = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("input") | Where-Object {$_.id -like "*_cbRunNow"}
$checkBox.click()

#click OK button, id ends with _OK

#OK

$OK = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("input") | Where-Object {$_.id -like "*_OK"}
$OK.click()
Start-Sleep -seconds 5;

$ie.Quit()
```

**Web Service:**

```
public string TriggerDataRefresh(string listId, string userId)
{           
    string status = string.Empty;
    string dataRefreshPSPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DataRefreshPSPath"];
    string refreshURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RefreshUrl"];
    refreshURL += "?list=" + listId + "&ID=" + userId;

    if (File.Exists(dataRefreshPSPath))
    {
        Process proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(dataRefreshPSPath);
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = dataRefreshPSPath;
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("\"{0}\"", "'" + refreshURL + "'");
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true; //tried false also
        proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;                    

        proc.Start();
        status = proc.Id.ToString();
    }
}
```

When I run the PS script alone it is opening IE browser. Not sure why it is not opening IE UI when triggered from web service.

Comment: Browsers and all other programs with UI behave very poorly in headless environments like web servers... Are you sure you need to launch browser on your server machine? (PhantomJs would be better option for such case)

Comment: Thank you, I am trying PhantomJS, will update once it works